# ffmpeg several files processing

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to process by ffmpeg many video files, located in upload directory on php. Processing is time cost, so i need to use some processing technique. What could you advise me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking about doing something similar using a bash script or a couple of bash scripts. Once you decide on how you will use ffmpeg you should be able to set up a watch folder so when files are added they start getting processed - once one is done it starts the next one - this is what I was thinking for my script anyway.